# tidyverse: cross_d()` is deprecated; please use `cross_df()` instead

Tags: r, tidyverse

I use `tidyverse`

```
results <- df %>% 
+   pipelearner(lm, yzp ~ .) %>% 
+   learn_cvpairs(k = 5) %>% 
+   learn()
```

And I get

```
Warning messages:
1: `cross_d()` is deprecated; please use `cross_df()` instead. 
2: `cross_d()` is deprecated; please use `cross_df()` instead.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Ignore it.

Long Answer: The author of the pipelearner package has to fix it. Presumably pipelearner internally uses the function `cross_d()` somewhere, which has been renamed to `cross_df()` in a more recent version of the package purrr. Deprecated means that the old function (name) still works as intended, but will be removed in the future. So the pipelearner author has some time to fix his package.